# Issues with running skype bot on server

Tags: c#, windows-server-2003, skype4com

So I have a skypebot which is running on Server 2003. I have skype installed and the bot is just a .Net executable. It works great, except when I try to have it run without me logged into the system.

It will run for a period of time, then the user session will end or something, and Skype will log off.

Trying to figure out what I can do about this.

Comment: We have succesfully deployed Skype bots ( https://sevabot-skype-bot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ubuntu.html ) on Linux servers. Skype is set to autologin and we'll simply restart the whole stack every night.

Answer (score 0):

Put your Bot in a windows service. Run the service under your account

Comment: The issue is that Skype keeps closing; not the bot. I can't seem to keep Skype active if the desktop session ends.